# Pros and cons of wrapping a number in a struct to avoid implicit conversions

Tags: c++, c, struct, overloading, idioms

I'm writing a small library with the following:

```
using foo_t = int;
using bar_t = int;

baz_t create_baz(foo_t foo, bar_t bar = default_bar);
```

and I also want to have a `create_baz` function which only takes a bar:

```
baz_t create_baz(bar_t bar);
```

but that will collide with the defaulted first version of create_baz - since `foo_t` and `bar_t` are the same. So, I was thinking: Perhaps I should have

```
struct foo_t { int value; }
struct bar_t { int value; }
```

(or just wrap one of them in a struct), so that the types will be different, and even incompatible, and I'll be have that second `create_baz`.

Now, obviously a struct is less convenient to use. But are there other pros and cons I should take into account about this decision?

My question is mainly about C++ but I suppose that's also somewhat relevant in C (ignoring the second parameter of the first function).

Comment: No answer, because I didn't have to solve something similar, just a thought: using the struct doesn't seem that inconvenient, writing `x = foo;` or `x = foo.value;` doesn't make a huge difference.  And you can still use `auto& v = foo.value;`if that would make the code clearer. Just make sure to document why you introduced the structs.

Comment: Using structs to separate different types of `int` values is viable in C. However, C doesn't have name mangling and hence no function overloading, so you would need different function names regardless.

Comment: `strong typedef` is something we do not have. But you can always Create a wrapper `IntClass` taking some user tag and define `operator int`  ?

Comment: @stefaanv: Well, you see, some of the code is not mine, so I have to force that on other people; and some of them will use int's due to other code, so they'll have to reconcile wrapped and unwrapped int's etc.

Comment: Why not a tag to disambiguate the call like the standard template library does with `std::allocator_arg_t`? That would be... Well, standard. :-)

Comment: @skypjack: Can you be more specific/provide a link?

Comment: @einpoklum I'm adding an answer with those details.

Answer (score 2):

The following is not an answer for your exact question, but `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` seems to work well for creating incompatible typedefs:

```
#include <boost/strong_typedef.hpp>
// Only the header is required. No linking, no runtime dependencies.

BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(int, foo_t);
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(int, bar_t);

void create_baz(foo_t foo, bar_t bar = static_cast<bar_t>(1)) {}
void create_baz(bar_t bar) {}

int main()
{
    // Assigning (or initializing with) literals seems to be 
    // the only inconvenient thing about strong typedefs.
    foo_t a = static_cast<foo_t>(1);
    foo_t b = static_cast<foo_t>(2);

    a = b; // Operators work well.
    std::cout << a+b << std::endl; // Even overloaded ones.

    create_baz(a); // No errors, no ambiguity.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this... but: 1. How is that different than wrapping with a struct, other than the definition of various operators? 2. What about going back to int? 3. It's problematic for me to create a dependency on Boost, even if only to include a header.

Comment: @einpoklum 1. Looks like no difference here. Boost just defined all the operators for you not to do extra work. 2. Do you mean `int c = a;`, where `a` is strongly typedef'ed? It works without any explicit casts. 3. OK, boost is often an unwanted dependency. As a workaround, you might compile `#include <boost/strong_typedef.hpp>` (this only line) with `g++ -E` or similar option of your compiler and include the output into your project as one more header.

Answer (score 1):

A common, basic and obvious technique to disambiguate a function call is adding an extra, parameter and rely on overloading.
It's so common that even a few classes in the standard template library uses it.

As an example, consider what's the purpose of [`std::allocator_arg_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_arg_t):

> [...] an empty class type used to disambiguate the overloads of constructors and member functions of allocator-aware objects [...]

It is used by `std::function`, `std::tuple`, `std::promise` and `std::packaged_task`.

You can easily look at the lists of constructors of those classes to know how it is used.

Another example is the postfix increment/decrement operator.
It has a *dummy* `int` parameter that helps to differentiate the function declaration from the the prefix increment/decrement operator.
That is:

```
T& operator++(T&)
```

Versus:

```
T& operator++(T&, int)
```

Here the call doesn't require you to provide that extra parameter and it serves only to disambiguate the function declarations actually, so it is a contrived example.

Anyway, what can you do in your case?
You can define a *tag* like this one:

```
struct bar_arg_t {};
```

And use it in the second function declaration:

```
baz_t create_baz(bar_arg_t, bar_t bar);
```

That is nothing more than an empty class, a dummy parameter the purpose of which is to help you disambiguating the call.